# Running Zookeeper 3.4.12 and Solr 6.5.1 with Systemd - Solr immediately shuts down after starting

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, systemd

I'm fairly new systemd and zookeeper. Please be patient, thanks.
Any help is appreciated!

The Setup:

- Suse 12 Enterprise
- No init.d, only systemd
- zookeeper 3.4.12 is running via systemd and listening on default port 2181
- solr 6.5.1 must also run via systemd, but immediately after start solr decide to shutdown for unknown reason
- solr.log shows establishing connecting to zookeeper and shortly after a warning and shutdown
- zookeeper logfile don't has not a single line about solr dropping out

I'm confused and unable to determine if this issue with systemd unit files or zookeeper <-> solr issue.

Questions:

- Is the unit file solr.service correct? (I'm not sure about that, examples on net are very scarse)
- Is this systemd issue or zookeeper problem?
- Which logs can I switch turn on to get more insight?

`As @MatsLindh points out this is an sytemd issue. Solr log WARN was just a coincident.`

journalctl -u solr

```
Sep 05 16:42:36 mucs75561 systemd[1]: Started Apache Solr Service.
Sep 05 16:42:40 mucs75561 solr[15732]: [98B blob data]
Sep 05 16:42:40 mucs75561 solr[15732]: Started Solr server on port 8983 
(pid=15857). Happy searching!
Sep 05 16:42:40 mucs75561 solr[15942]: Sending stop command to Solr running on port 8983 ... 
waiting up to 180 seconds to allow Jetty process 15857 to stop gracefully.
```

The solr.log tells a different story (tail -n 1000 -f  /opt/xxx/solr-6.5.1/server/logs/solr.log)

```
cat /opt/xxx/solr-6.5.1/server/logs/solr.log
16:42:38.594 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server jetty-9.3.14.v20161028
16:42:38.992 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter  ___      _       Welcome to Apache Solr™ version 6.5.1
16:42:38.996 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter / __| ___| |_ _   Starting in cloud mode on port 8983
16:42:38.996 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter \__ \/ _ \ | '_|  Install dir: /opt/xxx/solr-6.5.1
16:42:39.016 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter |___/\___/_|_|    Start time: 2018-09-05T16:42:38.998Z
16:42:39.017 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.StartupLoggingUtils Property solr.log.muteconsole given. Muting ConsoleAppender named CONSOLE
16:42:39.035 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader Using system property solr.solr.home: /opt/xxx/solr-6.5.1/server/solr
16:42:39.099 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter Loading solr.xml from SolrHome (not found in ZooKeeper)
16:42:39.100 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrXmlConfig Loading container configuration from /opt/xxx/solr-6.5.1/server/solr/solr.xml
16:42:39.413 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.u.UpdateShardHandler Creating UpdateShardHandler HTTP client with params: socketTimeout=600000&connTimeout=60000&retry=true
16:42:39.418 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.ZkContainer Zookeeper client=localhost:2181/solr
16:42:39.510 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.Overseer Overseer (id=null) closing
16:42:39.514 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.OverseerElectionContext I am going to be the leader 192.168.18.49:8983_solr
16:42:39.519 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.Overseer Overseer (id=72167078483197975-192.168.18.49:8983_solr-n_0000000009) starting
16:42:39.616 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.ZkController Register node as live in ZooKeeper:/live_nodes/192.168.18.49:8983_solr
16:42:39.622 INFO  (OverseerStateUpdate-72167078483197975-192.168.18.49:8983_solr-n_0000000009) [   ] o.a.s.c.c.ZkStateReader Updated live nodes from ZooKeeper... (0) -> (1)
16:42:39.812 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.CorePropertiesLocator Found 0 core definitions underneath /opt/xxx/solr-6.5.1/server/solr
16:42:39.898 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server Started @1864ms
16:42:40.549 INFO  (ShutdownMonitor) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Shutting down CoreContainer instance=966739377
16:42:40.557 INFO  (ShutdownMonitor) [   ] o.a.s.c.Overseer Overseer (id=72167078483197975-192.168.18.49:8983_solr-n_0000000009) closing
16:42:40.558 INFO  (OverseerStateUpdate-72167078483197975-192.168.18.49:8983_solr-n_0000000009) [   ] o.a.s.c.Overseer Overseer Loop exiting : 192.168.18.49:8983_solr
16:42:40.566 WARN  (zkCallback-5-thread-1-processing-n:192.168.18.49:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.c.ZkStateReader ZooKeeper watch triggered, but Solr cannot talk to ZK: [KeeperErrorCode = Session expired for /live_nodes]
16:42:40.566 INFO  (ShutdownMonitor) [   ] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for: solr.node
```

My /etc/systemd/system/solr.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Solr Service
After=syslog.target network.target nss-lookup.target
Requires=zookeeper.service

[Service]
User=xxx
Group=tomcat
WorkingDirectory=/opt/xxx/solr-6.5.1/
Environment=SOLR_INCLUDE=/opt/xxx/solr-6.5.1/bin/solr.in.sh   
ExecStart=/opt/xxx/solr-6.5.1/bin/solr start -m 4g -c -z localhost:2181/solr
ExecStop=/opt/xxx/solr-6.5.1/bin/solr stop -all

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Thanks, for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd [requires the service that it starts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394431/why-is-systemd-stopping-service-immediately-after-it-is-started) to remain running. Since the Solr startup scripts exits after starting Solr (i.e. it daemonizes the process and leaves it running in the background), systemd thinks it's dead and attempts to stop it.

You can start solr in the foreground with `bin/solr start -f`:

> ```
> -f            Start Solr in foreground; default starts Solr in the background
>               and sends stdout / stderr to solr-PORT-console.log
> ```

Comment: Specifying `Type=forking` in the unit file should also work, but yes, having the daemon start in the foreground is better.

Comment: @MatsLindh You are right. Systemd stops solr as you described.
My workaround: 
I declared a PID file in the unit file: `PIDFile=/opt/xxx/solr-6.5.1/solr-8983.pid`

I also udated solr.in.sh: `SOLR_PID_DIR=/opt/xxx/solr-6.5.1`

Comment: @LucasWerkmeister @MatsLindh I will checkout the `Type=forking` and `-f` option at later time.

Thanks!